# How to compare time in JS

Tags: javascript, time, format, comparison

How can compare two variables in JS with value as time string in the below format

```
Mon, 29 Feb 2016 09:09:53 GMT
Thu, 21 Jan 2016 05:08:46 GMT
```

Simply doing x > y will work ??? Or Do I need to convert into other format..

```
strtotime()
```

above function is available in php which will parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

Is there any function to do the same in JS ??

Comment: You can use lesser then or greater then operators but not equality `new Date() === new Date() // false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Date.parse('Mon, 29 Feb 2016 09:09:53 GMT') > Date.parse('Thu, 21 Jan 2016 05:08:46 GMT')
```

> true

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you should compare Date objects:

```
var foo = new Date("Mon, 29 Feb 2016 09:09:53 GMT");
var bar = new Date("Thu, 21 Jan 2016 05:08:46 GMT");

if(foo > bar) { ... }
```

There are multiple ways of creating an instance of the Date object. You can read more about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Storing the time string in a variable:

```
var foo = "Mon, 29 Feb 2016 09:09:53 GMT";
var bar = new Date(foo);
```

Comment: Is it possible to give a variable as a parameter for above method ??

Comment: It depends what you mean. I hardcoded the time values, but you can always set a variable to that string and pass it to the Date object. I've edited my original comment with an example.

Comment: Careful with this.  Two identical dates return false to any comparison operator. `var d1 = new Date("Thu, 21 Jan 2016 05:08:46 GMT");  var d2 = new Date("Thu, 21 Jan 2016 05:08:46 GMT"); console.log(d1 == d2, d1 === d2, d1 < d2, d1 > d2);` -> `false, false, false, false`;

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970:

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getTime();
</script>
```

Comment: Only reliable way to compare times in JS.  eg. Two `Date` objects created from the same exact string return `false` for any kind of comparison (`<`, `>`, `==`, `===`).